# .htaccess - sub domain always redirects to main domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I don't have much experience with .htaccess rewrite rules so I'm hoping that someone can help.

I've created a subdomain for a website that I want to use for development work however I think that the current .htaccess file is causing a redirect to the main domain. This is the current .htaccess file:

```
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^160\.153\.16\.12
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
```

The sub domain is dev.website.co.uk

Any advice will be very gratefully received.

Comment: you need to explain the structure of both sites. .htaccess can be placed ANYWHERE in your sites' document roots.

Comment: How come that the sub domain isn't in the .htaccess? it seems like this is not the right .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess has rules which tell it to redirect to the main domain. Just remove them from your subdomain's .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^160\.153\.16\.12
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

# I don't know what these are for
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many problems in your `.htaccess`, may be you have posted only part of it.

Main problem I see, the following lines catch any case where `HTTP_HOST` is different from `www.domain.co.uk` and redirect to `www.domain.co.uk`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The following catch any case `HTTP_HOST` is different from `^160\.153\.16\.12` and redirect to `www.domain.co.uk`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^160\.153\.16\.12
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As far as I know, the remaining `RewriteCond` are useless without a corresponding rewrite rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
```

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more
>   RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is
>   then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its
>   pattern, and if these conditions are met.

And at end, as @Marc B stated, you need to explain where the .htaccess is placed and if both the sites share the same root.